# MySQL - Slow query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry for the long post, but the tables involved are quite big.

When I run the query bellow it normally takes about 1m to run. However, when I remove the correlated sub-query I get the query down to 15 seconds. So I think that's the actual problem.

Problem is, I don't really know how to get the SUM results without the correlated query.

## QUERY I'm trying to run

```
SELECT cl_clients.vat as association_vat, cl_clients.name as association_name, cl_clients_with_regions.city_id, cl_clients_with_regions.nut_1, cl_clients_with_regions.nut_2, cl_clients_with_regions.nut_3,
       company.vat as company_vat, company.name, company.section, company.division, company.cae,
       SUM((
            SELECT SUM((COALESCE((cl_finances.sales_community_market), 0) + COALESCE((cl_finances.sales_extra_market), 0)))
            from cl_finances
            where cl_finances.vat =  company.vat
            and cl_finances.year = 2018
        )) as total_sum
FROM `cl_clients_with_regions`
JOIN `cl_client_intervention_areas` ON `cl_client_intervention_areas`.`city_id` = `cl_clients_with_regions`.`city_id`
JOIN `cl_clients` ON `cl_clients`.`vat` = `cl_client_intervention_areas`.`client_vat`
INNER JOIN cl_clients_with_regions company ON cl_clients_with_regions.vat = company.vat
WHERE `cl_clients_with_regions`.`encrypted_vat` IS NOT NULL
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`country` IS NOT NULL
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`cae` IS NOT NULL
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`cae` != ''
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`division` IS NOT NULL
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`section` = 'A'
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`nut_2` = 'Centro'
GROUP BY association_vat;
```

## CL Clients create table syntax

```
create table cl_clients
(
    vat                  varchar(20)                                                                                              default ''         not null,
    encrypted_vat        varchar(32)                                                                                                                 null,
    temporary_vat        enum ('0', '1', '')                                                                                      default '0'        null,
    sig_id               int                                                                                                                         null,
    phc_id               int                                                                                                                         null,
    client_manager       int                                                                                                                         null,
    name                 varchar(300)                                                                                                                null,
    brand                varchar(255)                                                                                                                null,
    `group`              varchar(200)                                                                                                                null,
    class_internacional  varchar(45)                                                                                                                 null,
    logoimage            varchar(400)                                                                                                                null,
    social_capital       varchar(100)                                                                                                                null,
    address              varchar(300)                                                                                                                null,
    gps                  varchar(25)                                                                                                                 null,
    parish               varchar(70)                                                                                                                 null,
    zip_code             varchar(10)                                                                                                                 null,
    city                 int                                                                                                                         null,
    district             int                                                                                                                         null,
    country              int                                                                                                      default 75         not null,
    headquarter          int                                                                                                                         null,
    person_title         varchar(7)                                                                                                                  null,
    person_contact       varchar(350)                                                                                                                null,
    person_phone         varchar(20)                                                                                                                 null,
    person_cell          varchar(15)                                                                                                                 null,
    person_email         varchar(150)                                                                                                                null,
    person_function      varchar(150)                                                                                                                null,
    language             varchar(10)                                                                                                                 null,
    phone                varchar(20)                                                                                                                 null,
    mobile_phone         varchar(20)                                                                                                                 null,
    fax                  varchar(20)                                                                                                                 null,
    email                varchar(50)                                                                                                                 null,
    email_alternative    varchar(50)                                                                                                                 null,
    website              varchar(300)                                                                                                                null,
    pme                  varchar(500)                                                                                                                null,
    pme_lider            varchar(500)                                                                                                                null,
    cae                  varchar(15)                                                                                                                 null,
    cae_2                varchar(15)                                                                                                                 null,
    certified            enum ('1', '0', '')                                                                                                         null,
    sector               varchar(350)                                                                                                                null,
    workers              int                                                                                                                         null,
    foundation_date      date                                                                                                                        null,
    size                 enum ('Micro Empresa', 'Pequena empresa', 'Média empresa', 'Grande empresa', 'Não aplicável', 'PME', '') default ''         null,
    company_type         varchar(455)                                                                                             default 'Empresa'  null,
    type                 enum ('novo', 'antigo', 'analizar', '')                                                                  default 'analizar' null,
    entity               enum ('client', 'prospect', 'suplier', 'potential', '')                                                  default 'prospect' null,
    client_to_country    int                                                                                                                         null,
    partner              enum ('1', '0', '')                                                                                      default '0'        not null,
    partner_dp           enum ('0', '1', '')                                                                                      default '0'        null,
    lucrative            enum ('1', '0', '')                                                                                      default '1'        not null,
    dun                  varchar(100)                                                                                                                null,
    debt                 enum ('50k', '100k', '500k', '1m', '5m', '+5m', '')                                                                         null,
    bankruptcy           enum ('1', '0', '')                                                                                      default '0'        null,
    competitors          enum ('1', '0', '')                                                                                      default '0'        null,
    dun_date             date                                                                                                                        null,
    bank_1               varchar(30)                                                                                                                 null,
    bank_2               varchar(30)                                                                                                                 null,
    bank_3               varchar(30)                                                                                                                 null,
    status               enum ('0', '1', '')                                                                                      default '1'        null,
    followup             enum ('0', '1', '')                                                                                      default '1'        null,
    classification       enum ('Prestige', 'Premium', 'Current', '')                                                              default 'Current'  null,
    associated           enum ('0', '1', '')                                                                                      default '0'        null,
    industry_id          int                                                                                                                         null,
    valid                enum ('0', '1', '')                                                                                      default '1'        null,
    imported_at          timestamp                                                                                                                   null,
    modified_by          int                                                                                                      default 0          null,
    responsible_id       int                                                                                                                         null,
    partner_type         int                                                                                                                         null,
    iberinform_id        int                                                                                                                         null,
    iberinform_date      timestamp                                                                                                                   null,
    legal_form           text                                                                                                                        null,
    going_concern        text                                                                                                                        null,
    score                int                                                                                                                         null,
    sector_score         int                                                                                                                         null,
    tax_status           text                                                                                                                        null,
    irc_debtors_ledger   enum ('0', '1')                                                                                                             null,
    ss_debtors_ledger    enum ('0', '1')                                                                                                             null,
    association_class_id int                                                                                                                         null,
    nature               enum ('business', 'commercial', 'sectorial', 'other')                                                                       null,
    geographic_scope     enum ('national', 'regional', 'local')                                                                                      null,
    intervention_nut     enum ('nut_1', 'nut_2', 'nut_3')                                                                                            null,
    ch_is_associated     enum ('0', '1')                                                                                                             null,
    bi                   enum ('0', '1')                                                                                          default '0'        null,
    updated_at           timestamp                                                                                                                   null,
    constraint encrypted_vat_UNIQUE
        unique (encrypted_vat),
    constraint vat
        unique (vat),
    constraint cl_clients_cl_caes_cae_fk
        foreign key (cae) references cl_caes (cae)
            on update cascade,
    constraint clients_industry_id_fk
        foreign key (industry_id) references cl_industries (id),
    constraint cltns_asso_clss_id_fk
        foreign key (association_class_id) references cl_association_classifications (id)
            on update cascade on delete set null,
    constraint country_fk_id
        foreign key (country) references cl_countries (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
);
 
create index cl_client_name_idx
    on cl_clients (name);
 
create index cl_clients_bi_idx
    on cl_clients (bi);
 
create index cl_clients_brand_idx
    on cl_clients (brand);
 
create index cl_clients_company_type_idx
    on cl_clients (company_type);
 
create index cl_clients_geo_index
    on cl_clients (city, district);
 
create index cl_clients_geographic_scope_idx
    on cl_clients (geographic_scope);
 
create index cl_clients_group_idx
    on cl_clients (`group`);
 
create index cl_clients_nature_idx
    on cl_clients (nature);
 
create index cltns_asso_clss_id_fk_idx
    on cl_clients (association_class_id);
 
create index country_idx
    on cl_clients (country);
 
create index fk_clients_industries1_idx
    on cl_clients (industry_id);
 
alter table cl_clients
    add primary key (vat);
```

### VIEW being used in the query

```
create view cl_clients_with_regions as
select `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`vat`                         AS `vat`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`encrypted_vat`               AS `encrypted_vat`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`name`                        AS `name`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`brand`                       AS `brand`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`country`                     AS `country`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`district`                    AS `district`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`city`                        AS `city`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_cities`.`id`                           AS `city_id`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_cities`.`name`                         AS `city_name`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_cities`.`nut_1`                        AS `nut_1`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_cities`.`nut_2`                        AS `nut_2`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_cities`.`nut_3`                        AS `nut_3`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`cae`                         AS `cae`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_caes`.`description`                    AS `cae_designation`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_caes_divisions`.`division`             AS `division`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_caes_divisions`.`division_designation` AS `division_designation`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_caes_divisions`.`section`              AS `section`,
       `grupoch`.`cl_caes_divisions`.`section_designation`  AS `section_designation`
from (((`grupoch`.`cl_clients` join `grupoch`.`cl_cities` on ((
        (`grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`city` = `grupoch`.`cl_cities`.`city_cod`) and (`grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`district` =
                                                                                `grupoch`.`cl_cities`.`district_id`)))) join `grupoch`.`cl_caes` on ((`grupoch`.`cl_caes`.`cae` = `grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`cae`)))
         join `grupoch`.`cl_caes_divisions`
              on ((`grupoch`.`cl_caes_divisions`.`division` = `grupoch`.`cl_caes`.`division_id`)))
where ((`grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`country` in (75, 185, 186)) and (`grupoch`.`cl_clients`.`vat` is not null));
```

## CL finances create table syntax

```
create table cl_finances
(
    vat                           varchar(20)    not null,
    year                          int            not null,
    workers                       int            null,
    sells                         varchar(300)   null,
    sells_variation               varchar(300)   null,
    international_sells           varchar(300)   null,
    international_sells_variation varchar(300)   null,
    liquid_results                varchar(300)   null,
    liquid_results_variation      varchar(300)   null,
    capital                       varchar(300)   null,
    active_liquid                 varchar(300)   null,
    financial_autonomy            varchar(300)   null,
    modified_by                   int default 0  null,
    sales_profitability           decimal(13, 2) null,
    return_on_capital             decimal(13, 2) null,
    sales_community_market        decimal(13, 2) null,
    sales_extra_market            decimal(13, 2) null,
    created_at                    timestamp      null,
    updated_at                    timestamp      null,
    primary key (vat, year),
    constraint clients_finances_vat
        foreign key (vat) references cl_clients (vat)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
);
 
create index cl_finances_year_idx
    on cl_finances (year);
 
create index vat
    on cl_finances (vat);
 
 
## Create table syntax for cl_client_intervention_areas
 
create table cl_client_intervention_areas
(
    client_vat varchar(20) not null,
    city_id    int         not null,
    constraint fk_cl_client_intervention_areas_cl_cities1
        foreign key (city_id) references cl_cities (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_cl_client_intervention_areas_cl_clients1
        foreign key (client_vat) references cl_clients (vat)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
);
 
create index fk_cl_client_intervention_areas_cl_cities1_idx
    on cl_client_intervention_areas (city_id);
 
create index fk_cl_client_intervention_areas_cl_clients1_idx
    on cl_client_intervention_areas (client_vat);
```

## The explain result from this query is quite big

[image: Image with the entire EXPLAIN result]

Comment: your image is almost unreadable

Comment: @nbk pleas open the image in a new tab and it will be full size. Sorry about that: https://i.imgur.com/DIs7MRu.png

Comment: Don't use a VIEW. They offer no practical benefit in MySQL

Comment: @Strawberry Without the use of a view I would need some serious help to get the desired result. Do you think I would get a performance increase if I wasn't using it?

Comment: @marcogmonteiro i opened izt in a new tab it is still unreadable, so please don't post images

Comment: @nbk The image has more than 2000px width. You can zoom in and out at least on chrome. Anyhow, Don't know how else I would post such big explain result. Any ideas so I can add it to the question making it more complete.

Comment: What is the point of the SUM function in the subquery?  Since (vat, year) is primary key for cl_finances, there should be only one matching row in each execution.

Comment: What is the purpose of "INNER JOIN cl_clients_with_regions company ON cl_clients_with_regions.vat = company.vat"?  It seems like a 1:1 mapping.  Why do you need two instances of the view?

Comment: It's not a 1 to 1. Its 1 - N. That view maps all the regions a client has activity in.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro So the view will have multiple rows for a given vat?  I do not have the definition of the other tables, but from EXPLAIN it seems the other tables can be accessed by eq_ref, and since vat is unique in cl_clients, I do not quite see how joining the view with itself on vat will generate a 1:N mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the subquery is being executed once per row in the group by clause.
Could you try the following if it makes it any better.

Change i have done is to perform the correlated query as a inline-view and then join with the main table/view -- company.vat

```
SELECT cl_clients.vat as association_vat, cl_clients.name as association_name, cl_clients_with_regions.city_id, cl_clients_with_regions.nut_1, cl_clients_with_regions.nut_2, cl_clients_with_regions.nut_3,
       company.vat as company_vat, company.name, company.section, company.division, company.cae,
       SUM(temp_val.sum_val) as total_sum
FROM `cl_clients_with_regions`
JOIN `cl_client_intervention_areas` ON `cl_client_intervention_areas`.`city_id` = `cl_clients_with_regions`.`city_id`
JOIN `cl_clients` ON `cl_clients`.`vat` = `cl_client_intervention_areas`.`client_vat`
INNER JOIN cl_clients_with_regions company ON cl_clients_with_regions.vat = company.vat
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cl_finances.vat
                 ,SUM((COALESCE((cl_finances.sales_community_market), 0) + COALESCE((cl_finances.sales_extra_market), 0))) as sum_val
             FROM cl_finances
            WHERE 1=1
              AND cl_finances.year = 2018
         GROUP BY cl_finances.vat     
            )temp_val
  ON company.vat=temp_val.vat
WHERE `cl_clients_with_regions`.`encrypted_vat` IS NOT NULL
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`country` IS NOT NULL
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`cae` IS NOT NULL
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`cae` != ''
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`division` IS NOT NULL
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`section` = 'A'
AND `cl_clients_with_regions`.`nut_2` = 'Centro'
GROUP BY association_vat;
```

Comment: This helped a lot with performance. It's still not perfect but on the server we're running this I don't think we can do much better. The query was taking about 45 seconds and now we got it down to about 15.

Comment: SInce (vat, year) is primary key, I think you can drop SUM and GROUP BY from the subquery.  Without GROUP BY and aggregation, MySQL will merge the subquery with the main query.  Not sure how much you will gain, but you will at least avoid creating an extra temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

To further explain the above answer:

Subqueries should never be in the select clause because they execute once per record that is returned / or calculated to return.  This causes the query to get slower and slower as the database gets larger.

Instead, the subquery should be in the FROM clause, and the result of the subquery should be joined to and selected.